# makefile does not consider the latest

Tags: makefile

I currently have something like this in my Makefile

```
PLAY?=$(shell ${BREW} --prefix)/bin/test
PLAY?=/usr/local/test/bin/go
```

Why is statement 2 not taking affect ? Is it not possible to reassign a value to PLAY variable in my Makefile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?=` in a Makefile sets a variable *only if it is not already set*.  Since the lines are read in order, the first one will set `PLAY` if it previously was not set, while the second one will never do anything, since by the time you get to it, `PLAY` will be set to something.

If you want to set a variable even if it was previously set (replacing the value), use `=` instead of `?=`

Note that a variable might be "set" to an empty string (by something like `PLAY=$(shell true)` or even `PLAY=`, which is not the same as it being unset.  You can unset a variable with
 `undefine PLAY`